# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV14

Tags: java, android, android-support-library, noclassdeffounderror, android-appcompat

I recently checked out one of my older projects and when I'm trying to start the app i get the following error:

```
09-02 01:17:27.283: E/AndroidRuntime(31734): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-02 01:17:27.283: E/AndroidRuntime(31734): Process: com.example.selectiontest, PID: 31734
09-02 01:17:27.283: E/AndroidRuntime(31734): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV14
09-02 01:17:27.283: E/AndroidRuntime(31734):    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegate.create(AppCompatDelegate.java:135)
09-02 01:17:27.283: E/AndroidRuntime(31734):    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegate.create(AppCompatDelegate.java:117)
09-02 01:17:27.283: E/AndroidRuntime(31734):    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.getDelegate(AppCompatActivity.java:456)
09-02 01:17:27.283: E/AndroidRuntime(31734):    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onCreate(AppCompatActivity.java:59)
09-02 01:17:27.283: E/AndroidRuntime(31734):    at com.jh.midicontroller.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:88)
09-02 01:17:27.283: E/AndroidRuntime(31734):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990)
09-02 01:17:27.283: E/AndroidRuntime(31734):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
09-02 01:17:27.283: E/AndroidRuntime(31734):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2278)
09-02 01:17:27.283: E/AndroidRuntime(31734):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
09-02 01:17:27.283: E/AndroidRuntime(31734):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
09-02 01:17:27.283: E/AndroidRuntime(31734):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
09-02 01:17:27.283: E/AndroidRuntime(31734):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
09-02 01:17:27.283: E/AndroidRuntime(31734):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
09-02 01:17:27.283: E/AndroidRuntime(31734):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
09-02 01:17:27.283: E/AndroidRuntime(31734):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
09-02 01:17:27.283: E/AndroidRuntime(31734):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
09-02 01:17:27.283: E/AndroidRuntime(31734):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
09-02 01:17:27.283: E/AndroidRuntime(31734):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

I set the support library v7 up like in http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html described.

[image]

Any thoughts?

Comment: Switch to android studio .

Comment: Remove the android-support-v13.jar from your project.

Comment: But I am using support v13.